# Applying switch command to populate the data of an OU in a treeview using powershell

Tags: powershell, switch-statement

I am trying to populate the OU data in a treeview using powershell.
I an trying to do it by using a switch command and not If else but getting an error as

```
ERROR: + ...             $_.Node.Nodes[$OU.Path].Nodes.Add($OU.Properties['name'], ...
ERROR: +                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
ERROR:     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
ERROR:     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray
ERROR:
ERROR: Cannot index into a null array.
```

Can anyone suggest on how we can use the Switch command in this case.?

Below is the switch command that i am using:

```
switch ($ou.Properties['name'])
                {
                    "TestAdmin"
                    {
                        # OU Path
                        $OUPath = "OU=TestAdmin, OU=$OUIT, OU=$BaseOU, $OUBaseDomain"
                        # Gather users within the OU
                        $GatheredUsers = (Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "$OUPath" -SearchScope OneLevel -Properties Name -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).Name
                        # Populate tree with Users Gathered
                        foreach ($User in $GatheredUsers)
                        {
                            #$_.Node.Nodes.Add($OU.Path, "$User", "$User").ImageIndex = 2
                            $_.Node.Nodes[$OU.Path].Nodes.Add($OU.Properties['name'], "$User", "$User").ImageIndex = 2
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your `foreach` loop:

```
foreach ($User in $GatheredUsers)
{
    $_.Node.Nodes[$OU.Path].Nodes.Add($OU.Properties['name'], "$User", "$User").ImageIndex = 2
}
```

`$_` contains the current object in the pipeline object. Since there is no pipeline, and you are using `foreach` with a named variable (`$User`) the `$_` variable is empty and doesn't reference anything and hence the error message.

i.e. how this is constructed at this moment `$_` does not reference any treeview control or anything else.

You have to replace `$_` with your treeview control object.